# Python getting the grouped values from positive look ahead

Tags: python, regex

for the following regex and input i'am able to get the group(1) match object.but how to get the match objects from positive look ahead?

[regex and input](https://regex101.com/r/1ntpp0/1)

regex is : (\w+)(?=\s*()|(?:(?<=,|())\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\s*(\w+)\s*)?

input is : PRIMARY INDEX FIRST_ONE ( PLATFORM_CD ,SYSTEM_NAME ,DB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME );

in this i'am able to get the index name ,which is 'FIRST_ONE'.
I also need to get the column names.how to do that?

I tried to get the group(2) but its returning None

the code I tried is :

```
upiOrPiValue = re.search(r'(\w+)(?=\s*\()|(?:(?<=,|\())\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\s*(\w+)\s*)?',line)
                print('line : ',line)
                #print('---->',upiOrPiValue)
                if upiOrPiValue == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    PiorUpiName = upiOrPiValue.group(1)
                    print('PiorUpiName : ',PiorUpiName)
                    print('upiOrPiValue.group(2) : ',upiOrPiValue.group(2))
```

upiOrPiValue.group(1) is returning the 'FIRST_ONE' value.how to fetch the column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement ***how to get the match objects from positive look ahead*** and later statements are a bit confusing. Assuming you want to capture index name `FIRST_ONE` and remaining column names, `PLATFORM_CD ,SYSTEM_NAME ,DB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME`, you can simplify your regex and use this to capture all you need.

```
(?:\w+)(?=\s*(?:\(|,|\)))
```

Python code for same,

```
import re
line = 'PRIMARY INDEX FIRST_ONE ( PLATFORM_CD ,SYSTEM_NAME ,DB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME );'
arr = re.findall(r'(?:\w+)(?=\s*(?:\(|,|\)))', line)
print(arr)
```

Which prints,

```
['FIRST_ONE', 'PLATFORM_CD', 'SYSTEM_NAME', 'DB_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME', 'COLUMN_NAME']
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for. Else please update your post to clarify your needs.

Comment: you answer works perfectly.The regex which I mentioned in question is grouping the values, but i'am only able to fetch the group(1) only although there are other match groups.how can we fetch those values?do you have any ides about that?your answer solved my problem but still I just wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

got the answer for the regex : (\w+)(?=\s*()|(?:(?<=,|())\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\s*(\w+)\s*)?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

regex = r"(\w+)(?=\s*\()|(?:(?<=,|\())\s*(\w+)\s*(?:\s*(\w+)\s*)?"
strVal = "PRIMARY INDEX FIRST_ONE ( PLATFORM_CD ,SYSTEM_NAME ,DB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME );"

matches = re.finditer(regex, strVal)

for match in matches:
    for gCount in range(1, len(match.groups())+1):
        if match.group(gCount) != None:        
            print(match.group(gCount))
```